# Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (Connection: mysql, SQL: select * from `produits` where `id` in (1)) : laravel

Tags: laravel

##### Destroy function:

```
public function destroy(string $id)
{
    Produit::destroy($id);

    return redirect('produits')->with('lash_message', 'produits deleted!');
}
```

##### Migration

```
Schema::create('produits', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id_produit');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

How can I change the id to the id I put in table (`id_produit`)?

Comment: `Produit::where('id_produit', $id)->delete()` or maybe `Produit::find($id)->delete()`?

Comment: `destroy($id)` (and `::find($id)`) will only work if your `Produit` model has it's `protected $primaryKey` property set to `'id_produit'`: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#primary-keys

Answer (score 2):

This is probably because your model that you want to delete is not using the custom column "id_produit" you provided as a primary key. By convention, Laravel models use the 'id' as their primary key. Since in your case it doesn't exist, when it tries to delete something by it, the query fails.

Two possible solutions in this case:

1. You change the

```
$table->increments("id_produit");
```

to

```
$table->increments("id");
```

The advantage of this approach is that it sticks to the Laravel conventions and probably makes it easier to make relationships to other models in the future, because you wouldn't have to manually specify your foreign_key_id names and primary_key names.

2. The quicker solution is to specify the name of the column that is the primary key in the model. You can do that by defining a class attribute in the Produit model like this:

```
class Produit extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'id_produit';

    // other model code here...
}
```

Even though it's not standard convention, this is also completely fine, and you can find these use cases in many apps.